# Show "bonus pool" of consumables in game

Tags: mobile-application, info-visualisation, games

In my game I have two types of consumables "shuffles" and "bombs". Every game you get three of each. Here is what the top portion of the game looks like:

[image]

Now I want to introduce in app purchases that will allow you to buy 15 more of each at any time. These 15 "bonus" items will be added to your 3 default and persist between games (minus however many of them you use). So if in one game you use your 3 starting bombs plus 4 bonus bombs you will start the next game with 3 default plus only 11 bonus.

I need way to display this second pool of items that hopefully shows they are different but work the same, also in a visually appealing way. I can give the details of "these persist between games etc" on the purchase screen but it'd still be nice to imply it visually.

Bonus question: I'm not entirely sure "bonus" bombs fits for items that you pay for, to me bonus says a free reward. Is there a better word for this?

Answer (score 5):

Put a +15 after the default 3 and give it a different color, perhaps whatever color is used for the in app purchased currency.

When the player uses the default / bonus and the see the respective number dropping, they will quickly learn that they are two different pools of items.

You could also add some small icon/tooltip next to the 3 or +15 to imply that the items perish/persist

[image]

> Bonus question: I'm not entirely sure "bonus" bombs fits for items that you pay for, to me bonus says a free reward. Is there a better word for this?

Call it Extra Bombs

Answer (score 1):

You can change the icon such as a dynamite maybe? the word bonus can be replaced with "Special"?

I don't know how is your game looks like, but maybe you can add  a different effect for the dynamite/the purchased one when the users use it.

Comment: Very interesting I didn't consider using a different "type" such as dynamite for the purchased ones. That wouldn't work so easily for the "shuffle" consumables though. Definitely getting ideas though!

Comment: how about "additional" to replaced "bonus"?